# reverse_lazy with no arguments not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

reverse_url is workin fine with a url that has-no/int:pk but does not work with a url that has /int:pk throws an error NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'read_bty' with no arguments not found. 1 patterns tried:['read_bty/(?P[0-9]+)$']. The first (class=HBTYIndex) lists all customers created from the (class=HBTYCreateView) and the (class=HBTYReadView) displays the customers order records, the last (class=HBTYOrderView) is supposed to create an order and reverse_lazy to the url 'read_bty' but it keeps on throwing the above error when creating an order. Tried to change from int:pk to int:id still getting the same error. if i change the reverse_lazy to point to a url with no int:pk the record gets added and i get redirected to that page instead of staying on the same page and showing the new added record.

Views.py

```
class HBTYIndex(generic.ListView):
model = HbtyCustomers
context_object_name = 'bty'
paginate_by = 100
template_name = 'accounts/modals/bty/clientindex.html'
ordering = ['-id']
success_url = reverse_lazy('btylist')

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = self.model.objects.all()
    p_f = CustomerFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return p_f.qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = CustomerFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    return context

# Create Customer
class HBTYCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/bty/create_hbty.html'
    form_class = btyForm
    success_message = 'Success: Client was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('btylist')

# View Customer Orders History
class HBTYReadView(generic.ListView):
    model = HbtyOrder
    context_object_name = 'bty'
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/bty/read_hbty.html'
    allow_empty = False
    pk_url_kwargs = 'hbtycustomer_pk'
    paginate_by = 100
    ordering = ['-id']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('read_bty')

    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(hbtycustomer_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        p_f = HbtyOrdersFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return p_f.qs
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = HbtyOrdersFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

# Create New Order in the customer history page
class HBTYOrderView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/modals/bty/create_hbty.html'
    form_class = HairbtyOrderForm
    success_message = 'Success: Order was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('read_bty')
```

**read_hbty.html**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
      {% if filter.qs %}
        {% include "accounts/modals/hairbty/vw_more.html" %}
      {% else %}
        <p class="no-books text-primary">No Client addeds yet.</p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Models.py**

```
class HbtyCustomers(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
date = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class HbtyCategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class HbtySubcategories(models.Model):
    categ = models.ForeignKey(HbtyCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class HbtyOrder(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
            ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
            ) 

    categ = models.ForeignKey(HbtyCategories, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    subcateg = models.ForeignKey(HbtySubcategories, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    hbtycustomer = models.ForeignKey(HbtyCustomers, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('btylist/', views.HBTYIndex.as_view(), name="btylist"),
path('create_btycustomer/', views.HBTYCreateView.as_view(), name='create_btycustomer'),
path('create_btyorder/', views.HBTYOrderView.as_view(), name='create_btyorder'),
path('read_bty/<int:pk>', views.HBTYReadView.as_view(), name='read_bty'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell from your urls.py, read_bty/HBTYReadView wants to see an int value named pk.

When you call that url in HBTYOrderView via reverse_lazy, you don't provide it, hence the error.

You can build out the success_url by creating a get_success_url method in your HBTYOrderView, rather than using a success_url property, something like:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('read_bty',kwargs={"pk": self.request.user.id} )
```

(I am assuming here that the ID that read_bty wants is the request.user.id )

Comment: Thank You for the response, thought there is no user.id the form redirects me with a success message that the order has been added successfully. But its redirecting me a customer with id of 1